# Twenty-seventy theme remove additional CSS from head

Tags: plugin-development, css, admin-css

Is it possible that additional CSS that we add in customizer section, display somewhere else instead of head? I am using twenty-seventy theme. I know its fetch and rendering code is available in wp-include/theme.php something like this

```
function wp_custom_css_cb() {
    $styles = wp_get_custom_css();
    if ( $styles || is_customize_preview() ) :
        $type_attr = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'style' ) ? '' : ' type="text/css"';
        ?>
        <style<?php echo $type_attr; ?> id="wp-custom-css">
            <?php echo strip_tags( $styles ); // Note that esc_html() cannot be used because `div &gt; span` is not interpreted properly. ?>
        </style>
        <?php
    endif;
}
```

But i wish i remove this from head and add in some other separate file.

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to make a child theme and put the extra CSS in there, assuming that you don't need to keep editing this from the admin site and you don't have a plugin that's generating extra custom CSS dynamically. If you really did want to serve it from a static file then you could hook the functions in theme.php to save it to a file on disk when the custom_css post is written and include a link to that instead, but that seems like a lot of work and wouldn't support plugins adding custom CSS dynamically.

Comment: Or you could add a PHP endpoint that serves the custom CSS and link to that too I suppose, but then you'd be loading the whole of WordPress an extra time per page so that doesn't seem worth it.